# Jqgrid select option return key instead of label

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid 4.8.0, inline edit mode
Colmodel look:
`My_dynamic_option depends on       Options

```
                {
                    label: 'Options',
                    name: 'Options',
                    width: 150,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "select",
                    formatter: "select",
                    editoptions: {
                        value: GetOptionsData(),
                        dataInit: function (e) {
                            if ($(e).val() != null) {
                                var entId = $(e).val();
                                var dynamicOptions = GetDynamicPropertyForOptionData(entId);
                                if (dynamicOptions != null && dynamicOptions.length > 0) {
                                    var retstr = '';
                                    $.each(dynamicOptions, function (index, val) {
                                        if (index != 0) {
                                            retstr += ";";
                                        }
                                        retstr += val.Id + ":" + val.dynamicpropertyoptionname;
                                    });
                                    jQuery("#jqGrid").setColProp('My_dynamic_option', { editoptions: { value: retstr } });
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        dataEvents: [
                                {
                                    type: 'change',
                                    fn: function (e) {
                                        if ($(e.target).val() != null) {
                                            var entId = $(e.target).val()
                                            var rowid = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                            if (rowid != null) {
                                                var row = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
                                                var rowId = row.attr('id');
                                                var dynamicOptions = GetDynamicPropertyForOptionData(entId);
                                                if (dynamicOptions != null && dynamicOptions.length > 0) {
                                                    var newOptions = '';
                                                    $.each(dynamicOptions, function (index, val) {
                                                        newOptions += '<option role="option" value="' +
                                                        val.Id + '">' +
                                                        val.dynamicpropertyoptionname + '</option>';
                                                    });
                                                    $("select#" + rowId + "_My_dynamic_option", row[0]).html(newOptions);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                        ]
                    },
                },
                {
                    label: 'My_dynamic_optionId',
                    name: 'My_dynamic_optionId',
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'text',
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'My_dynamic_option',
                    name: 'My_dynamic_option',
                    width: 150,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "select",
                    editoptions: {
                    value: { '': '' },
                            dataEvents: [
                            {
                                type: 'change',
                                fn: function (e) {
                                    if ($(e.target).val() != null) {
                                        var dynamicSetId = $(e.target).val();
                                        var rowid = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'My_dynamic_optionId', dynamicSetId);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }`
```

My_dynamic_option depends on Options.
My_dynamic_option can contains a lot of value(more than 1000), so loading them all in grid loading – is not good idea.
So, I decided load My_dynamic_option. dynamicpropertyoptionname into My_dynamic_option column, to show it to user.
And load My_dynamic_option.id into hide column(to keep correct value into grid) - My_dynamic_optionId
They loading correctly, and grid look fine.
But after save value instead normal label in My_dynamic_option column I’m getting Id.
Load, all look great:
http://s15.postimg.org/itjhey5aj/load.png

[image]

After save:
http://s3.postimg.org/kcqe0adw3/save.png

[image]
And this is a problem

Comment: Why you fill `val.Id` if you don't want that it will be used? Why not use `val.dynamicpropertyoptionname + ":" + val.dynamicpropertyoptionname` instead of `val.Id + ":" + val.dynamicpropertyoptionname`? Moreover there are exist `dataUrl` option of `editoptions` created *exactly for dynamic loading*. If the response returned by the server have JSON format instead of HTML fragment with `<select>` than you can use `buildSelect` to convert JSON data to `<select>`. It would be the standard way.

Comment: Sorry Oleg, but i cannot use a standart way, my server understand only XMLHttpRequest with special header and so on.

Comment: About using `val.Id + ":" + val.dynamicpropertyoptionname` - I need use it in other thing.

Comment: There are `ajaxSelectOptions` option which allows to customize any options of Ajax request. For example you `ajaxSelectOptions: { dataType: "xml"}` or to use `beforeSend` to set custom HTTP options. If you includes the code of `GetDynamicPropertyForOptionData` I could show which standard options can be used to make the same Ajax call. Your question is still not clear enough. You wrote about some problems with saving, but you don't wrote **which editing mode you use** and even **which version (or which fork) of jqGrid you use**.

Comment: The description "I need use it in other thing" gives no information too. If you use `edittype: "select"` without `formatter: "select"` it means that you fill jqGrid with texts and not with values. So the correct usage of `<select>` which changes the values should be with texts too. If you need hold another values associated with every select option you should save there in any other attribute, but not in `value`. `data-xxx` attributes could be used for example. If you want help from other people you should explain your question more detailed for other readers.

Comment: Sorry, Oleg, I tried to make my question clear.

Comment: Is `dataInit` is the property of `My_dynamic_option` column or another column? Sorry, but I still don't understand what you do and what you wand to implement. It's probably more clear if you describe all on an example. Which columns you have (1-2), which data you get from the server, what will be sent to the server after editing now and what you would like to send.

Comment: I rewrite my question and add some explain pictures

Answer (score 2):

Hello

You can use this to get the ID and the property value from your grid

```
var myGrid = $( "#gridID" ),
var rowId = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
var cellValue = myGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', rowId, 'My_dynamic_option');
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found!
It's more easy and more strange.
If you have 2(or more) "select" column, you column without `formatter: "select"` must be last `edittype: "select"` column(it could not the last column in col model, but it must be last select column), other way - it would be bug, which i had.
Thanks for help!

update

If you will use colmodel like this(and jqGrid 4.8, inline edit mode):

`{
    label: 'Select without formatter',
    name: 'Select_0',
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
    edittype: "select",
    editoptions: { value: “FE:FedEx; IN:InTime; TN:TNT” }
},
{
    label: 'Select with formatter',
    name: 'Select_1',
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
    edittype: "select",
    formatter: "select",
    editoptions: { value: “FE:FedEx; IN:InTime; TN:TNT” }
}`

It would:
1.Show you in col: `Select_0` id(code) instead of select label
2.In function like `jqGrid('getRowData', rowid)` with needed rowid it would return code in column Select_0, instead of label.

But, if you replace your columns like this:

`{
    label: 'Select with formatter',
    name: 'Select_1',
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
    edittype: "select",
    formatter: "select",
    editoptions: { value: “FE:FedEx; IN:InTime; TN:TNT” }
},
{
    label: 'Select without formatter',
    name: 'Select_0',
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
    edittype: "select",
    editoptions: { value: “FE:FedEx; IN:InTime; TN:TNT” }
}`

It would be correct behaviour(as I expect: would show label, and `jqGrid('getRowData', rowid)` would return label in column Select_0)

Comment: Sorry, but you still **don't described** "the bug". You just posted some part of code without `colModel`, without any example of data which you loads dynamically. You say: there is a bug. Could you post clear demo and the test case (expected results after the following steps and the results which one have instead) which can be used to reproduces the problem?

Comment: Oleg, sorry again, I tryed explain it.

Comment: The code which you posted have syntax error: there are **no comma after `formatter: "select"`**. Try to fix the syntax error (insert the comma) and repeat the test.

Comment: Oleg, it's a copy-past error, in real - I have a comma.